# how to use the see more button to display more array using angular

Tags: angular

I created an array and displayed it in component, by `ngFor` directive, with a `see more button,` I want to display 4 array elements at the beginning, and when I click on the button it displays other 4 elements and so on respectively, until the end of the array, the button will be hidden.

**more.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'more',
  templateUrl: './more.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./more.component.css']
})
export class MoreComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  courses:any[]=[
    'laravel','symfony','angular','react',
    'laravel1','symfony1','angular1','react1',
    'laravel2','symfony2','angular2','react2',
    'laravel3','symfony3','angular3','react3',
    'laravel4','symfony4','angular4','react4',
    'laravel5','symfony5','angular5','react5',
  ];
}
```

**more.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let cours of courses">
    {{ cours }}

</div>
<button>See More...</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a variable "count" an [slice pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe)

```
count:number=1;

<div *ngFor="let cours of courses|slice:0:count*4">
    {{ cours }}

</div>
<button *ngIf="count*4<courses.length" (click)="count=count+1">See More...</button>
```